# scraping numbers from multiple pages based on an initial list of numbers

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Say I have a list of numbers (hundreds, e.g. 3, 11, 34 up to 200)

I'd like to automate the following process for each number:

1. Go to a webpage, enter the number in the search box and hit enter, the following tag of the search box comes back on the desired page like:

   ```
   input id="myid" type="text" name="yadda[goTo][number]" value="3"
   ```

So value="3", 3 is the number in my initial list.

2. Then on that page, extract the following tag (just the first one, there may be multiple similar ones):

   ```
   meta content="website.com/yadda1/yadda2/dfd_I1123_35362542_1d8sw31124a.jpg" />
   ```
3. I only want the 35362542 number from this tag, and then to have a table that matches the initial number, e.g. 3, with this number.
4. repeat for all the numbers in the initial list

What's the best way of doing this? Beautiful Soup?

Comment: Yes is a good way using `BeautifulSoup` and `requests`. Can you provide the html of the search and results pages ?